# Best way to manage versions separately for 2 directories in the same project

Tags: android, android-studio, svn

My Android project looks like this

```
...
     src/
       main/
         java/
           ...
           Services/
                Service1.java
                Service2.java
                Service3.java
           MainActivity.java
           Class1.java
           ...
```

That means that i have a package named Services under the main package.
Currently, the whole source code (src folder) is managed in one Subversion repository.
I want to separate Services folder from the rest of the project in terms of version control.I want to manage my project so that i can go back to past version in my Services package without changing the actual app (the rest of the project) and vice versa.

What is the best way to do this assuming that i want to stick to SVN? I tried to open another repository and work with 2 different repositories but it seems impossible to change the working directory to a child directory (Services is a child directory of src)

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding from your question you need to have independent configuration for your service with rest of your app.

You can go with `Library like structure`. Create a separate module for your `services` package and separate for rest of project. Include service module as a `dependency` to Main module, by this you will have two respective `gradle` files with separate configurations.

```
Your Project
       |
       |
       Main Module
             |
             |
             Service module
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. My questions is regarding the actions that i need to make in order to manage version control. i.e use one repository or 2 separate? how to configure this on Android Studio?

Comment: Is the solution that you offered, enables SVN to control 2 modules under the same repository? Or a convenient way to work with 2 repositories in parallel?

Comment: @AmitBedarshi It will be handle under one repo , your are just migrating two modules.